# How do I assign a return strongly typed object value to a Label text?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure in which I imported as a function in my entity framework model.   I want to assign one of the values of the stored proc to my label.text but it doesn't appear in the intellisense.   I must be doing something wrong.   Can someone please assist?

```
    private void GetBackgroundData()
    {
        List<GetBackground_Result> results = context.GetBackground().ToList();
        lblFullName.Text = results.FullName  // FullName doesn't appear in my intellisense
    }
```

Comment: "results" is a list and as far as I know a `List<T>` doesn't have the `FullName` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is a List, not a single instance of `GetBackground_Result`. You need to take a single element from the collection to set the text:

```
// if there could be multiple elements in the list
lblFullName.Text = results.First().FullName;

// or, if there should only be one element in the list
lblFullName.Text = results.Single().FullName;
```